# Clipping line features to polygon in SQL Server

Tags: clip, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to clip a rivers layer to a polygon layer in a view. Below is the code that I tried but I receive an error (i.e. `SQL Error [4145] [S0001]: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'`).

```
--CREATE VIEW v_BC_River AS
SELECT C.OBJECTID AS ObjectID, replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(C.FULLNAME, 'Crk', 'Creek'), 'Riv', 'River'), 'Lk', 'Lake'),'Br','Branch'),'Frk', 'Fork') AS Name, Data_Authority = 'US Census Bureau', C.Shape.STIntersection(M.Shape)
FROM CENSUS_RIVER AS C JOIN CLIPPINGPOLYGON4MAPS AS M ON C.SHAPE.STIntersects(M.Shape);
```

Comment: I think you need to add `= 1` after `C.SHAPE.STIntersects(M.Shape)` so `C.SHAPE.STIntersects(M.Shape) = 1`